# 2 domains in the same space htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, subdomain

I'm not familiar with htaccess file,,

I have a main domain (mainsite.net)
and another domain (site2.com)
all of them are in the same space. and (site2.com) is in a folder under the (mainsite.net).

when I enter (site2.com) it says:
( Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.)

I need a code that I could put in my htaccess file - which on (mainsite.net) root- , that makes me able to open (site2.com) without getting this message.

Comment: Can you post `mainsite.net/.htaccess` and `site2.com/.htaccess`?

Comment: Don't post them in comments, no one can read it. Add them to your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `site2.com/.htaccess` with this content:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
ErrorDocument 500 default
ErrorDocument 401 default
ErrorDocument 403 default
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
RewriteEngine On
```

Comment: I added .hatccess , but nothing changed :(

Comment: now it just said :
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
*note : every site has a different script and site2 now just have a simple index.html file...

Comment: that one worked perfectly ! thank you so much for quick answering !